# Can I Store HealthKit Data In The Cloud If It's Not iCloud?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, cloud, icloud, healthkit

I am working on an app that uses health data from the iOS HealthKit SDK, and I of course want to have a duplicate of that data for my own server-side analysis.  I know that you can't save HealthKit data in iCloud, and I've read the [Apple Developer Guidelines for HealthKit](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#healthkit), but it doesn't address the use of cloud in general other than iCloud in particular.  Am I allowed to store health data in Parse or another cloud?

Comment: Did you ever get the answer to this?

Comment: @TruMan1 Unfortunately not.  Hopefully the question gets reopened.

Comment: So is there anyway of getting the data from healthkit without an iOS app

Comment: @julianjoseph HealthKit is available to iOS, WatchOS, and Mac Catalyst. Other than that, there is no way to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you have to explicitly state in the app that you will be exporting HK data to an external server. If you do not do this, Apple will reject your app.

I would also suggest reading through the [Protect User Privacy](https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014707) section of the HK documentation.

Comment: Can you provide a source for this?  I didn't see cloud mentioned in the Protect User Privacy link.